# Injecting JS into Literal and firing after page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, literals

I have an ASPx/C# page that on clicking Save it will post back to the server.  If the content within the controls already exists in the data stores which are checked it is supposed to pop-up an alert.  The previous programmer used:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litError" runat="server" />
```

with the code behind ultimately sending:

```
litError.Text = "<script type='javascript'>alert('An error occured while processing this request.  If the error persists, please contact the help desk.');</script>";
```

This JS alert is not popping up in spite of the debug reporting everything correctly processing through.  I have scoured the internet, including here, for several days trying to find a resolution.  I have tried many variations to get this to fire.

I'm suspecting that the script cannot fire on the AJAX because it is just not there during the Load stage of the life cycle, but would like some verification.

The script is in the btnSave_OnClick method.  Unfortunately, due to the nature of the web application I cannot show more of the code, but the script should fire on exception of an item existing in either the app DB or if the user exists in our AD system already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by completely removing the use of the ASP Literal control.  I believe my first attempts at using this didn't have a properly formatted string, but it is now correctly functioning with the below code implemented in the code behind:

```
StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();
        sbError.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('" + strError + "');</script>");

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "sbError", sbError.ToString(), false);
```

Thanks to Zaigham and James for trying to help.  I believe the reason the Literal control method did not work was because there was a ScriptManager control on the page(s) that were attempting to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why the script in literal is not working, but you can try this instead.

Your script text

```
 string script = "<script>alert('Your alert message goes here');</script>";
```

Then use the method `RegisterClientScriptBlock` (in the same event where you previously set the error text) to inject the script to the page during the postback.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(YOUR_PAGE_TYPE), "alert", script);
```

When the page is loaded back, you should see the alert popped up.

Comment: I tested your suggested example and had the same results.  I'm beginning to think another piece of JS is prevent the alert from happening.  I'll have to sit with the original developer to decipher his logic I think!

Comment: If you think another script is causing the issue, you may want to look in to the developer console of the browser. Usually they will contain some useful error details.

Comment: I will most certainly be doing this today.  I'll try to get back here to report my findings as well.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand is; you want to run client script from code behind in the button click event (based on a condition). The best way to achieve this is to use ScriptManger class. Example:

```
Protected void btnSave_OnClick()
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSave, btnSave.GetType(), "myscript",
     "alert('Your alert message goes here');", true);
}
```

Comment: I had the same results using this method.  I'm starting to think that the problem lies in other JS or possibly even the fact that this lives in a callback in a content space of a master page.

If you have any further suggestions I would be happy to try them, but even the current code taken out of the project and ran alone works correctly.  The issue has to be when it is passed off or on the callback.

Comment: can you check the browser console if there is a script error that occurs before that script which is making this script code to not run at all?

Comment: I will most certainly be doing this today.  I'll try to get back here to report my findings as well.

Comment: The logs do not show any errors.  Back to tinkering.